# how to save and fetch button enable and disable value using Userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I want to save the button enable and disable value in userdefault. I wrote the following code but nothing happened. Please tell me how to save and fetch button enable and disable value.

I want, when the ibaction button is pressed, it should disable and when closes the app and reopen the app then it should save the disable state of button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//        let def = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
//        btn1.isEnabled = def

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let def = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
    print(def)
        //btn1.isEnabled = def

}

@IBAction func btn1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let def = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
    print("Button one pressed")

    let otherAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Button 1!!", message: "Here is button one.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in

        print("OK pressed")
        self.btn1.isEnabled = false
         UserDefaults.standard.set(self.btn1.isEnabled, forKey: "val")
    }
    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
    self.btn1.isEnabled = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.btn1.isEnabled, forKey: "val")

        print("No pressed")

    }
    otherAlert.addAction(dismiss)
    otherAlert.addAction(okaction)

    present(otherAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let def1 = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
    btn1.isEnabled = def1
}


@IBAction func btn2Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("Button Two pressed")
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see where you synchronize  UserDefaults after set.

Comment: you don't need to synchronize anymore

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving `self.btn1.isEnabled` save the value you are applying to that. Can't you do this directly ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        // You need to check if key is present or else you will get false as default value and your button will disabled only
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "val") {
          let def = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
          btn1.isEnabled = def
        }
}

// Check key is present or not
func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
   return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
}

@IBAction func btn1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.set(false, forKey: "val")
    print("Button one pressed")

    let otherAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Button 1!!", message: "Here is button one.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        print("OK pressed")
        self.btn1.isEnabled = false
        defaults.set(false, forKey: "val")
    }

    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
        self.btn1.isEnabled = true
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "val")
        print("No pressed")

    }
    otherAlert.addAction(dismiss)
    otherAlert.addAction(okaction)

    present(otherAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // No need of these 2 lines
    let def1 = defaults.bool(forKey: "val")
    btn1.isEnabled = def1
}
```

Comment: then how we fetch it and where we this value

Comment: i tried you above code, this is also not working. please see this after disabling the button and save and fetch value alert should not show

Comment: @UmairAhmad Tell me if this is what you want. If you click the button for first time, button should be disabled and if you close and reopen your app then it should be disabled only. Am I right ?

Comment: bro it is not working.. Can you also write a fetching statement for it and can you also test it ?

Comment: please see this... i am fetching through this way
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        let def = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val")
 
        
    }

Comment: @UmairAhmad yes that's correct. There is an alert when you click on button, what is the functionality of that. Also I updated my code please test the latest one. If you press OK value will be false and if you press NO value will be true in your viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Please stay here.. I check it

Comment: bro i check it... it is not disabling the button and it disables the button when click on yes.. but when app closes and reopen alert again shows

Comment: @UmairAhmad in viewDidLoad add this btn1.isEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "val"). Press OK in alert, kill the app and open it again, it should be disabled now.